# How to extract strings from json

Tags: php, json

I have to extract strings from a xml file. One particular value has been generated using json enconding.
Here is a exemple of what I can find:

```
<plus_details>
[["Neuf"],["Petite copropri\u00e9t\u00e9"],["Vue mer"]]
</plus_details>
```

I would like to extract the strings and display them inline and separated by commas, like this :

Neuf, Petite copropriété, Vue mer

I tried using json_decode function, but the only thing I can display is:

```
array(3) {
[0]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
string(4) “Neuf”
}
[1]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
string(20) “Petite copropriété”
}
[2]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
string(7) “Vue mer”
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you got it parsed and decoded correctly. If you need another data structure you could easily loop over the result and generate what you want. You can also access the values directly from the resulting array like `$result[0][0]`, `$result[1][0]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use a loop to go through your data. When you json_decode the string you provided us, you will end-up with an array like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Neuf
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Petite copropriété
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Vue mer
        )

)
```

So in order to get your data you need to loop your array.

```
foreach(json_decode($json) as $data){
    echo $data[0];
    echo '<br>';
}
```

The output of the above code is:

```
Neuf
Petite copropriété
Vue mer
```

Comment: I just added the array to explain why i used the loop and how i ended up extracting the strings the OP wanted. I think now is more clear for a step by step solution

Comment: If my answer helped you solve your question please mark it as accepted for future users as well.